# What's the difference between addToPrincipalPolicy vs addToPolicy

Tags: amazon-iam, aws-cdk

In CDK IAM Users, Groups or Roles have two methods to add PolicyStatements:

1. X.addToPolicy ([CDK API Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_iam.Group.html#addwbrtowbrpolicystatement)) and
2. X.addToPrincipalPolicy ([CDK API Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_iam.Group.html#addwbrtowbrprincipalwbrpolicystatement))

Whats the difference between then?
The API Reference isn't much help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**TL;DR**  Both add a statement to a Principal's inline policy.  The only difference is the return value.

Both accept a [PolicyStatement](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_iam.PolicyStatement.html) and synth a `AWS::IAM::Policy` resource to the Principal.  However, `addToPolicy` returns a "success" boolean, while `addToPrincipalPolicy` returns an [object](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_iam.AddToPrincipalPolicyResult.html).

This is easy to see by looking at the [aws-cdk source](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/blob/master/packages/%40aws-cdk/aws-iam/lib/role.ts#L214) implementation of the `Role` class:

```js
// role.ts 
export class Role extends Resource implements IRole {
  // ...

  public addToPolicy(statement: PolicyStatement): boolean {
    return this.addToPrincipalPolicy(statement).statementAdded;
  }

  public addToPrincipalPolicy(statement: PolicyStatement): AddToPrincipalPolicyResult {
    if (!this.defaultPolicy) {
      this.defaultPolicy = new Policy(this, 'Policy');
      this.attachInlinePolicy(this.defaultPolicy);
    }
    this.defaultPolicy.addStatements(statement);
    return { statementAdded: true, policyDependable: this.defaultPolicy };
  }
```

Comment: Also, if you have a role sourced via `Role.fromRoleArn` (ie. an IRole), you cannot use `addToPolicy` (only `addToPrincipalPolicy` is implemented on IRole).